# Eclipse - show overring method specific return value

Tags: java, eclipse, visual-studio-code, search

Usually I have a parent class with method as:

```
 abstract boolean validate();
```

Where I want to know all sub classes that return certain value, as

```
 boolean validate() {
     return true;
 }
```

How can this be done in eclipse? This is a general question where return value can be Object as String and checking for  methods returning null values

Comment: Most IDEs will quickly show you all the implementations of your abstract method. I think you'll need to inspect them manually though to determine what they return.

Comment: I doubt there's a built-in way to search for a method that returns a particular literal value, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: @shmosel if not possibble, is there a workaround? Can I see first/last lines of each methods in search reaults

Comment: Your best bet is probably a simple regex, like `boolean\s+validate\(\)\s*\{\s*return\s+true;`. Of course that wouldn't work with comments, constants etc.

Comment: @dave I have dozens of metods, is there a workaround?

Comment: Dozens doesn't sound like a huge amount, tbh. Should take a few minutes to look through them.

Comment: @shmosel can this option I request be consider as a valid enhancememt request?

Comment: Doesn't seem like something that would have broad applicability, but that's just my opinion. You can probably build a plugin though.

Comment: If that were general possible, the [halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem) would also be solvable. `return true;` can be also written as `return (('a' | 'b') % 8 == 3);` or even as `return System.currentTimeMillis() > 0;`.

Comment: @howlger yes, but maybe there's an option for simple "constant" values? or at least show in search results more relevant rows

Comment: Define _simple_. In your example, should also `return Boolean.TRUE;` be found? Should only methods without parameters and containing only a `return` statement be searched for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to search using regular expression including new line, now in VS code:

```
validate\(\) \{\n(\t+)(.+)return true
```